# Show all instance variables set on a class?

Tags: php

I have wondered how I can show all my instance variables in PHP?

```
 <?php
class User {

 private $activeId = 0;

 public function __construct($id=NULL){
    $this->activeId = $id;
 }

 public function save(){
     //show all the variables automaticly
 }
}


$user = new User();
$user->username="Jesper";
$user->email="lol";
$user->save();
?>
```

`$user->save()` should print out variables: "username","email","save" so i can call ex. `$this->username`

So if I make ex. `$user->blablabla = "asasas";` it should also show that.

In other words, all the variables i have set in $user->xxx

Comment: [`get_object_vars($this)`](http://us.php.net/get_object_vars).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function save() {
    $vars = get_object_vars($this);
    foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
        echo $key, ' -> ';
        var_dump($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($this)` is a lot shorter you know...?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes `var_dump` would not help with the OP's problem in the slighest.

Comment: var_dump($this) is less formattable... my example could easily be extended to make it more human and less computer readable

Comment: @MarkBaker agreed on the flexibility, I was just remarking that it's an *icing on the cake* solution, not the shortest possible answer :) +1 from me anyway.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I think you didn't read the question properly then, if all answers center around its use.

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the end:

```
var_dump($user);
```

To make it more readable on systems without XDebug installed put an `echo '<pre>';` before it.